# Why is chrome indicating a missing image on top of a CSS sprite?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, css-sprites

I am developing an app with jquery mobile, while everything seems to work great there is a indicator of a missing image within the mobile simulator of chrome desktop:

[image]

The code for the button:

```
<input type="image" id="search_icon" alt="Suche" onsubmit="submitForm();" class="sprites-searchicon searchiconList searchLeftFullNormalSearch">
```

All CSS classes exist.

Why is there an error indicator on top of the search icon?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image#src
`<input type="image" />` actually requires a `src`. You can set this src to the search icon, or just set a blank 1x1 pixel gif (or base64 even), then the broken image indicator should disappear

Comment: Unfortunately, we need more information. Please attach also the content of HEAD tag.

Comment: @Gajotres Hm? How is this not enough information? The OP's line of code is enough to reproduce the issue. What do you need the <head> for?

Comment: Because we are talking about jQuery Mobile which heavily modifies page content. Without the head content, I cannot know what is affecting the input tag.

Comment: @elveti Thank you, that fixed it. Used <span> instead of <img>. I am wondering why my question received a downvote, the question seems clear and your answer helped me to solve it. SO is getting pretty negative these days ...